# Can GIT behave like SVN?

Tags: git

I'm new to GIT, Received a requirement from my management as Can GIT behave like SVN?
i.e can all interactions be made with server(Centralized Version Control system) instead of user level(Decentralized Version Control System) such that branching and merging can be made easier?

Comment: please clarify: if you want svn-like behavior, why are you using git?

Comment: How does a centralised VCS make branching and merging even just a bit easier?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Git works very differently from svn and even trying to map ideas from svn to git will confuse you. It's safer and a better long term investment to take some time to study git properly so that you can work with it properly rather than try to use it like you would subversion.

Comment: This is one of those things where unfortunately management needs to sit down and learn something new before making decisions. Because the answer to this is both YES and NO depending on exactly what you want. Can it behave exactly like SVN? NO. Can it completely replace SVN (as in, you won't find any missing features)? YES.

Comment: Every organization which uses build automation obviously has a single repository which the builds are made from. Regulating who gets to push there and when is a social and policy matter, not a technical problem (though e.g. some sort of company-internal GitHub clone will help clarify which repo is central, as well as further leverage the benefits of moving to git).

Comment: Plus, the ability to work on a temporary clone while figuring out how to automate builds will shield you from having your learning experience exposed as a string of "ooops, try this instead" commits to the official repository. Build from your private repo until you have it figured out, then rebase away the oopses when merging your changes to the master.

Comment: @Shep I haven't worked at one company that gives me a choice.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [subgit](http://subgit.com/). This allows you to work with git and store the results in subversion. This is nice for testing your workflows and see how well things work with git.

**However** git is *not* svn! If you simply replace the tool and don't adapt your workflow and the mindset of the people it really makes no sense to switch and the migration will likely fail.

First find a good reason, *why* you want to switch. What are the current problems in your workflow. What do you want to change and why. After that you can look at tools and see which one suites your needs best.

Just using some random tool, because some people say it's cool was never a good idea. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible to define one canonical repository as the "center" of your workflow, and nearly all projects use this. A DVCS only *allows* you to link repositories (and often developers within a feature will add each other as remotes for easier sharing without pushing to the main repo).

If you want a linear history, git doesn't have any builtin way of enforcing this, but it would be possible to write a git hook to reject any commit with more than one parent. However, I strongly suggest *not* using a hook, just a review policy ("rebase all pull requests before submitting"), because you'll occasionally actually need to do a merge, and logical merges are *really* dirty in the SVN model.

Answer (score 0):

You will get everything in GIT that you want to do with SVN. For details,please mention your specific requirements. All you will need a central git repository everyone clones from. Branching and merging in GIT is lightweight and faster compared to what you get in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific what you need.

If you just want to have a copy of all commits, you may use a `post-commit` hook for that. That's more a workflow issue.